# Laravel model to get specific piece of data

Tags: laravel

I am trying to make a function that will help me get needed data quickly.

With all the trials I have been able to get to the following

**Tables**:

Users (id,name)

Projects (id,name)

User-Project (id, user_id, project_id, manager)  where manager is a boolean , there can only be one manager for each project (but employees can still see the project reason why we have a pivot table, manager = 0 for other normal users that can access that project)

In the Project Model I have:

```
  public function Manager(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->wherePivot('manager', true);
}
```

In the View I have:

```
 <p><strong>Project Manager:</strong> {{$project->manager}}</p>
```

On the actual page I get:

```
Project Manager: [{"id":4,"name":"Daniel Doe","email":"danieldoe@hotmail.com","phone":"70846556","email_verified_at":null,"created_at":"2020-12-20 21:05:50","updated_at":"2020-12-20 21:05:50","pivot":{"project_id":1,"user_id":4,"manager":1}}]
```

When I change the view to:

```
<p><strong>Project Manager:</strong> {{$project->manager[0]->name}}</p>
```

I get:

```
 Project Manager: Daniel Doe
```

This is what I actually want but I would like to do it from the model if possible. So I tried:

```
public function Manager(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->wherePivot('manager', true)->first()->name;
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
must return a relationship instance
```

Can this be done from the model's function?

Comment: `belongsToMany()` returns a Collection, i.e. multiple records. Your function name should be `managers` to reflect this. Next, if your requirements are *"there can only be one manager for each project"*, **why are you using a function and database structure that returns many Managers?** It should be `public function manager(){ return $this->hasOne(...) }`, and your `projects` table should have a `manager_id`, not a pivot table between them... Your requirements and coding do not match. You can still have the pivot to link `users` to `projects`, but drop the `manager` column.

Comment: because the project can have multiple users but only one manager, I edited the question, thank you for pointing out.

Comment: Yeah, see my edited comment; you can still have the `project_user` pivot table for that relationship, but it should be separate from `manager` (in my opinion anyway). I can see an argument for both ways, but it's a little off. I'll post an answer for how to do it with your current structure; 1 sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep your defined relationship, but to access `->first()->name`, you'll need to use an "Accessor":

```
public function manager() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->wherePivot('manager', true);
}

public function getManagerNameAttribute() {
  return $this->manager->first() ? $this->manager->first()->name : 'No Manager';
}
```

Then, in your code, you simple access:

```
{{ $project->manager_name }}
```

If your `manager()` function returns a Collection of at least 1 record, it will return the name, otherwise it will display 'No Manager' as a fallback.

Comment: thank you, it works perfectly. I am going to need to google the concept of "accessor" to learn why it works :)

Comment: Here you go: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor :) Laravel Models are pretty magical when you dig into em

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to change the structure of this you can use an accessor to get this information, roughly something like this:

```
class Project ...
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(...)->withPivot(...);
    }

    public function getManagerAttribute()
    {
        return $this->users()->wherePivot('manager', 1)->first()?->name;
    }
}
```

You can do this in different ways, you could use the loaded `users` relation and use a the Collection methods to filter the manager. You could create another relationship called `managers` that uses the `wherePivot` off of `users()`, etc ...

The only thing to worry about with this setup is that every call to `$model->manager` would be causing that query, so it may be a good idea to create another relationship `manager` so that you can load that once and keep using it without the need to keep querying the database:

```
public function managers()
{
    return $this->users()->wherePivot(...);
}

public function getManagerAttribute()
{
    return $this->managers->first()?->name;
}
```

Though, as mentioned already it is probably better to have something like a `manager_id` on the Project itself.

Comment: This is definitely cleaner. Wish the `?` null-safe operator was available earlier than PHP8 though :)

Comment: @TimLewis yea, i have moved everything to PHP8 an only use it now ... tooooooo many good features buddy `:)`

Comment: I wish I could; I read the "what's new in PHP8" page and squealed like a child on Christmas, but until I can convince management to move to it, we're stuck on 7. Some day though :)

Comment: as long as i had at least 7.4 i would be pretty happy